# Create a Form from table without foreign key Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Can someone please help advise how to create a form with drop downs based on a table in the database. I do not have a primary key in the table to link it as a foreign key.

However I would like to create form with a basic input text field with cascading drop downs from the table. Any expert who can advise how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: you cannot have a table without a primary key . if its not explicitly given , it will auto add

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField) and provide a `queryset` from which you would like to generate select options. For example,

```
# suppose you would like to generate select from table <your_app>.<Model>
class RelationForm(forms.Form):
    field = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=<Model>.objects.all())

# would yield
<select id="id_field" name="field">
  <option value="obj1.pk">Object1</option>
  <option value="obj2.pk">Object2</option>
  ...
</select>
```